# How do I compare values of BigInteger to be used as a condition in a loop?

Tags: java, biginteger

I am trying to compare if the value of one BigInteger(base) is `>` (greater than) the value of another BigInteger(prime) and if the value of 'a' is not equal to one. If value of a is not 1, it should break out of the loop. How should I compare them?

```java
Random ran = new Random();
BigInteger prime = new BigInteger(16,ran);
BigInteger base,a,one;
one = new BigInteger("1");

for (int i = 0; i < 65535; i++){

    while (base>prime){
        base = new BigInteger(16,ran);
    }
    a = base.modPow(prime.subtract(one),prime);
    System.out.println("a: "+a);    
    if (a != one){
        break;          
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can compare them using [`BigInteger.compareTo(BigInteger)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigInteger%29).

In your case, this would be `while (base.compareTo(prime) > 0) {...}`.

Also, your termination condition should be changed from `if (a != one)` to `if (!a.equals(one))` since two `BigInteger` variables with the same integer value are not necessarily referencing the same object (which is all that `==` and `!=` test).

Answer (score 8):

Since `BigInteger`s are objects, you should use caution when using the equality operators. Right now, you're performing a reference comparison (which in this case, will more than likely fail). You'll need to use the `equals()` or `compareTo()` methods.

BigInteger has a built-in static variable representing one. Use the `equals()` method or the `compareTo()` method to compare values:

```
if (!a.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    ...
}
```

-or-

```
if (a.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps! See here for more information: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: It looks like he needs both compareTo and equals. See here: "...and if the value of 'a' is not equal to one. If value of a is not 1, it should break out of the loop." In addition, his code shows a check for equality between the new BigInteger he made called "one" and the other calculated value "a". Sorry for the outdated link.

Comment: Fair enough, I missed the `if (a != one)` bit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
while (base.compareTo(prime)>0){
//rest of your loop
}
```